# Civi webform: change error message for unique entry

Tags: webform-civicrm

Civi webform where I have a field 'existing contact' as an autocomplete. It needs to be unique i.e. one per contact (in this case contact = Constituency), so I have checked 'Unique' in the field settings.

When you submit the form with a non-unique value you get the error message:

> The value 106320 has already been submitted once for the Constituency
>   field. You may have already submitted this form, or you need to use a
>   different value.

Is there anyway to show the contact Display name instead of the ID in this error message?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently no. Technically this field simply stores an integer (contact ID) and that's all the webform module knows about. There is probably a way to override this error message to supply the contact name via a hook but would require some work by a developer. A [pull-request](https://github.com/colemanw/webform_civicrm) for this improvement would be welcomed.